# Change styles with multiple select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change styles CSS with multiple select, but my code, unfortunately, is bad. Please see my code. What wrong? I would like to use "if" statement because I have sometimes a lot of styles to change in one select. For example SELECT number "1" will have 5 styles to changes but SELECT number "2" will have only 1 styles to change.
Any idea?

https://jsfiddle.net/129ax3bk/6/

```js
function changeBackground() {
  var box = document.getElementById('box');
  var colors = document.getElementById('colors').value;
  var textcolor = document.getElementById('textcolor').value;

  if (colors.value = "yellow" && textcolor.value = "black") {
    box.style.background = "yellow"; // YELLOW + BLACK
    box.style.color = "black";
  } else if (colors.value = "yellow" && textcolor.value = "white") {
    box.style.background: "lightyellow"; // YELLOW + WHITE
    box.style.color = "white";
  } else if (colors.value = "blue" && textcolor.value = "black") {
    box.style.background: "blue"; // BLUE + BLACK
    box.style.color = "black";
  } else if (colors.value = "blue" && textcolor.value = "white") {
    box.style.background: "lightblue"; // BLUE + WHITE
    box.style.color = "white";
  }
}
```

```css
#box {
  background: red;
  color: black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<select name="colors" id="colors" onChange="changeBackground()">
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>

<select name="textcolor" id="textcolor" onChange="changeBackground()">
  <option value="black">Black Text</option>
  <option value="white">White Color</option>
</select>

<div id="box">
  Text
</div>
```

Comment: I put your code in a snippet. You can see from the console you have several errors, notably the use of `=` instead of `==` when checking for equality

Comment: oh, thank you! you're right. I change = to ==.Console:
"changeBackground is not defined at HTMLSelectElement.onchange"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several issues with your code:

- You're using `=` for an equality comparison instead of `==`
- You use `:` to separate the setter of `background` from the value instead of `=`
- You're using `background` instead of `backgroundColor`
- You're attempting to access the `value` property of both `colors` and `textcolor` when they are strings and can be used directly.
- There's no `yellow` option in the `select`

With that in mind, try this:

```js
function changeBackground() {
  var box = document.getElementById('box');
  var colors = document.getElementById('colors').value;
  var textcolor = document.getElementById('textcolor').value;

  if (colors == "yellow" && textcolor == "black") {
    box.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"; // YELLOW + BLACK
    box.style.color = "black";
  } else if (colors == "yellow" && textcolor == "white") {
    box.style.backgroundColor = "lightyellow"; // YELLOW + WHITE
    box.style.color = "white";
  } else if (colors == "blue" && textcolor == "black") {
    box.style.backgroundColor = "blue"; // BLUE + BLACK
    box.style.color = "black";
  } else if (colors == "blue" && textcolor == "white") {
    box.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue"; // BLUE + WHITE
    box.style.color = "white";
  }
}
```

```css
#box {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<select name="colors" id="colors" onChange="changeBackground()">
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>

<select name="textcolor" id="textcolor" onChange="changeBackground()">
  <option value="black">Black Text</option>
  <option value="white">White Color</option>
</select>

<div id="box">
  Text
</div>
```

As you've tagged the question with jQuery, I'd suggest this alternative which instead separates the styling rules in to CSS and simply applies the specified class which is stored in the option value:

```js
$('#colors, #textcolor').change(function() {
  $('#box').removeClass().addClass($('#colors').val() + $('#textcolor').val());
});
```

```css
#box {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
#box.yellowblack {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}
#box.yellowwhite {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  color: white;
}
#box.blueblack {
  background-color: blue;
  color: black;
}
#box.bluewhite {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="colors" id="colors">
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>

<select name="textcolor" id="textcolor">
  <option value="black">Black Text</option>
  <option value="white">White Color</option>
</select>

<div id="box">
  Text
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! You are AMAZING! :D

Comment: I have one extra question. I have a #BOX with SVG element. SVG element has class .st9 with "fill: #fff". How to change fill in this class? I tried "st9.style.fill = '#000';" but in console: "Cannot set property 'fill' of undefined at changeBackground"

Comment: I'm not sure you can set the fill of a canvas element through CSS. I'd suggest asking a new question, I'm sure someone with more experience of canvas will answer it for you

Comment: Ok! Thank you!! :)